# Scala/Play: javax.xml.soap request header Content-Type issue

Tags: java, scala, soap, playframework, playframework-2.0

I've got this simple call to a SOAP API in my Scala/Play application:

```
import javax.xml.soap._


object API {


    def call = {

        val soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance
        val soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection

        val url = "http://123.123.123.123"

        val soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest, url)

        soapConnection.close

    }


    def createSOAPRequest = {

        val messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance
        val soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage
        val soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart

        val serverURI = "http://some.thing.xsd/"

        val envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope
        envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ecl", serverURI)

        val soapBody = envelope.getBody
        val soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("TestRequest", "ecl")
        soapBodyElem.addChildElement("MessageID", "ecl").addTextNode("Valid Pricing Test")
        soapBodyElem.addChildElement("MessageDateTime", "ecl").addTextNode("2012-04-13T10:50:55")
        soapBodyElem.addChildElement("BusinessUnit", "ecl").addTextNode("CP")
        soapBodyElem.addChildElement("AccountNumber", "ecl").addTextNode("91327067")

        val headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders
        headers.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "TestRequest")      
        headers.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic wfewefwefwefrgergregerg")

        println(headers.getHeader("Content-Type").toList)

        soapMessage.saveChanges

        soapMessage

    }
```

The `println` outputs the right `Content-Type` header that I've set:

```
List(application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8)
```

But the remote SOAP API that I'm calling responds with `415`:

```
Bad Response; Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

I've checked the request being sent with wireshark and indeed, the `Content-Type` header is wrong:

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
```

Why is the content type I set being ignored in this case and what do I do to fix it?

**UPDATE:** I think I'm on to something here:

A SOAPPart object is a MIME part and has the MIME headers Content-Id, Content-Location, and Content-Type. Because the value of Content-Type must be "text/xml", a SOAPPart object automatically has a MIME header of Content-Type with its value set to "text/xml". The value must be "text/xml" because content in the SOAP part of a message must be in XML format. Content that is not of type "text/xml" must be in an AttachmentPart object rather than in the SOAPPart object.

[source](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPPart.html)

Just need to figure out how to change my code to match this.

**UPDATE2: SOLVED** Just needed to change 1 row to indicate that this is SOAP 1.2:

```
val messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to change 1 row to indicate that this is SOAP 1.2 and the right header is set automatically:

```
val messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance(SOAPConstants.SOAP_1_2_PROTOCOL)
```